# How to find general form of sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, sequence-of-function

Please, I would like to express some fractions {$\dfrac{8}{35}$, $\dfrac{5}{21}$, $\dfrac{8}{33}$} in the general form

$$
\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}
$$

as for exemple for the form $$ \dfrac{f(n)}{g(n)}= \dfrac{(2n+1)(n+1)}{2n+3}$$

we find

$\dfrac{1}{3}$ for $n=0$, $\dfrac{6}{5}$ for $n=1$, $\dfrac{15}{7}$ for $n=2$, ....

Comment: Too little elements oto figure out reasonable well a general term.

Comment: It is definitely possible to express this finite sequence of numbers as a rational sequence (i.e. polynomial divided by a polynomial), and this can be done in many ways. Is there a particular purpose you had in mind for this? Would you care if, say, the next term was over ten thousand?

Comment: No particular purpose just fraction.

Comment: There are many questions on this website about finding the next term in a sequence, and I encourage you to track down a few of them and read through to see just how complicated this simple-seeming question can be, Gallagher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Ok, our comrades in the mathematica community found me the general form on [mathematica.stackexchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/218249/build-general-form-of-an-infinite-sequence/218251#218251), it's

$$\dfrac{n^2+4 n+3}{4 n^2+16 n+15}=\dfrac{(n+1) (n+3)}{(2 n+3) (2n+5)}$$

which gives for $n\gt0$: $\,\,\dfrac{8}{35}, \dfrac{5}{21} ,\dfrac{8}{33} ,\dfrac{35}{143},\dfrac{16}{65} ,\dfrac{21}{85} ,\dfrac{80}{323},...$

This can be useful for others.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We can always find a unique polynomial of degree at most $n - 1$ that goes through $n$ points, provided the $x$ coordinates are all different. For the numerator, we could use a polynomial $f(n)$ of degree at most $2$ such that $f(0) = 8$, $f(1) = 5$, and $f(2) = 8$. That is, a polynomial through the points $(0, 8), (1, 5), (2, 8)$.

Let $f(n) = an^2 + bn + c$, where $a, b, c$ are unknown constants. Then, we must have
\begin{align*}
8 &= f(0) = 0a + 0b + c \\
5 &= f(1) = 1a + 1b + c \\
8 &= f(2) = 4a + 2b + c.
\end{align*}
We can solve these simultaneously for $a, b, c$. The first equation tells me $c = 8$, so the second two equations just boil down to
\begin{align*}
-3 &= a + b \\
0 &= 4a + 2b.
\end{align*}
We can see from the first equation that $b = -3 - a$, so plugging into the second equation,
$$0 = 4a + 2(-3 - a) \implies 4a - 6 - 2a = 0 \implies 2a = 6 \implies a = 3.$$
We can then see that $b = -3 - a = -3 - 3 = -6$. So,
$$f(n) = 3n^2 - 6n + 8.$$

We can then use a similar method to find a $g(n)$ so that $g(0) = 35$, $g(1) = 21$, and $g(2) = 33$. I'll let you try this for yourself. This gives us the function $f(n)/g(n)$, as requested.

Comment: It's good. I found: $$g(n)=13n^2-27n+35$$. Thank you @user759562 for this method.

Comment: @Gallagher You're welcome!

Comment: Is this  the unique solution?

Comment: @Gallagher It's not unique, really. There is always a unique polynomial of degree $n$ through $n + 1$ points, but this doesn't preclude higher dimensions. We can also get other solutions by treating, say $5/21$ as $10/42$ or $-100/(-420)$, etc.

Comment: Ok. user759562, please how to express these polynomials as factors: $(....)(....)/(....)(....)$?

Comment: Quadratics are easy enough. You can find the roots using the quadratic formula (call them $p$ and $q$) and write $a(x - p)(x - q)$, where $a$ is the coefficient of $x^2$. The wrinkle is, $p$ and $q$ may not be rational, or real (which is the case for the numerator). If you insist on having these polynomials be factorable over the integers, then this is now a much trickier problem.

Comment: Sorry, I add below new elements which complete my fractions, $$\dfrac{8}{35}, \dfrac{5}{21} ,\dfrac{8}{33} ,\dfrac{35}{143},\dfrac{16}{65} ,\dfrac{21}{85} ,\dfrac{80}{323},... $$. As you see, above solutions don't give these values. Any ideas please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105977/discussion-between-gallagher-and-user759562).

Comment: Somone has an idea please.